# How to interpret the coefficient of an independent binary variable if the dependent variable is in square roots?

Tags: regression-coefficients, dependent-variable

I am trying to analyse the impact of a trade policy on exports. My dependent variable for the main specification is log of exports but as a robustness check, I want to include a linear transformation that is square root of exports (sqrtexp). On running regressing sqrtexp on a binary independent variable, I get a beta coefficient of -1.197. I have read another post on this about using the chain rule to interpret it. In my case, using the chain rule, change in y = 2(b1)^2 which equals 2.87 and implies, for X=1, the exports will change by $2.87. But still that doesn't make sense since its too small a change for exports that are for some products as high as in millions, which means I'm still interpreting the coefficient incorrectly. I'll be grateful for any insights on this!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "chain rule"? But if you want to use derivatives, for $\log(y)$ the response is proportional to $y$, because $\partial{\log(y)}=\partial{y}/y$. Similarly, for $\sqrt{y}$ the response is proportional to $\sqrt{y}$, because $\partial{(\sqrt{y})}=\frac{1}{2}\partial{y}/\sqrt{y}$. The "millions" would come from multiplying the coefficient by this scale.

Comment: Am sorry if that was confusing, I was referring to this (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35982/how-to-interpret-regression-coefficients-when-response-was-transformed-by-the-4t) post that talks about using a chain rule for interpretation. I'm simply trying to figure out how to interpret the beta coefficient of a binary variable when the dependent variable Y is in square roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an equation
$$
\sqrt{y} = a + bx
$$
Then you can evaluate the effect of changing $x$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$ by
$$
\Delta\left(\sqrt{y}\right) = \sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_0} =
\left(a + b x_1\right) - \left(a + b x_0\right) = 
b\left(x_1 - x_0\right) = b\Delta{x}
$$
If the change in $y$ is [small enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal), you can replace the finite differences $\Delta$ with differentials $\partial$, to get an expression for the derivative $dy/dx$. This is where the "chain rule" would come up, i.e.
$$
\partial\left(\sqrt{y}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial{y}}{\sqrt{y}}
$$

However for a binary $x$, where $x_1=1$ and $x_0=0$, you cannot necessarily do this, because $\Delta{y}=y_1-y_0$ may be too large. Instead you must solve the difference equation algebraically, i.e. if we write
$$
\beta = b\Delta{x} = \sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_0}
$$
then
$$
y_1 = y_0 + 2\sqrt{y_0}\beta + \beta^2
$$
and
$$
\Delta{y} = \beta\left(2\sqrt{y_0} + \beta\right)
$$
If $\beta = b\Delta{x}$ is small enough, then this reduces to the "chain rule", i.e.
$$\lim_{\beta\to{0}}\Delta{y} = 2\beta\sqrt{y_0}$$

For a continous $x$, you can ensure $\beta$ is small enough by considering an infinitesimal $\Delta{x}$. But for a binary $x$, where $\beta=b$, in general you must use the more general form, i.e.
$$
\Delta{y} = b\left(2\sqrt{y_0} + b\right)
$$
(if $b^2 \ll y_0$ this still reduces to the "chain rule" form).

Note that the scale of the response $\Delta{y}$ is set by $y_0$, which takes care of the "millions" in your case.

(Also note that your formula using $b^2$ does not allow for a negative response, which would also suggest something is wrong there. The correct formula above does not have this problem.)