# Interpretation of regression coefficients after power transform (possibily with polynomial transform and PCA)

Tags: regression, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, sensitivity-analysis

In general I standardize my features before regression by subtracting the mean and dividing by unit variance:
$$ \hat{X} = \frac{X - \bar{X}}{Var(X)}$$
With this basic standardization, interpreting the regression coefficients is quite straight-forward.

Now I've got some not-really-normal-dist data, for which a **power transform** is a good choice. Since some features contain negative values, I chose to use a **Yeo-Johnson** transformation. (I could also transform the features containing neg. values to all-positive features if Box-Cox helps the cause...)
After this transform, the data is **standardized** additionally, again by stubtracting the mean and dividing by variance.

#### Question:

Is there **an easy way** to interprete the regression coefficients after a power transform (may it be Yeo-Johnson or Box-Cox...)?
A similar question is asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35982/how-to-interpret-regression-coefficients-when-response-was-transformed-by-the-4t) and the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36110/225096) helps with the fact that feature scaling changes the coefficient interpretation in general, but it is specific to a transformation with the 4th root.

---

#### beyond the question

After the power transformation, I apply **polynomial** transformation of degree 2 or 3 with interaction terms and then perform a feature extraction with a **PCA** to reduce the dimensionality of the problem. Finally the design matrix is passed to a regression algorithm.

I guess this further reduces the intepretability for both only standardizing and/or power transform?
Any other way to interprete the coefficients **by using words?** (A graphical interpretation using ICE-plots and the like is imho still fairly easy.)

Comment: My answer that you reference is explicitly *not* specific to the fourth root: at the end it points out the easy generalization where the power $1/4$ equals any nonzero number $p.$  That answers your question.  BTW, a polynomial transformation is an exceedingly rare and tricky beast because (a) it is difficult to interpret and (b) unless its coefficients are carefully chosen, it's not even a transformation: it will not be one-to-one.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I expressed it a bit vague, but I was looking for a *specific answer considering the differences in coeff. interpretation between standardization and power transform*, thus my question imho requires a more answer. What do you mean by "one-to-one"? Considering standardized/power-transformed features?

Comment: I can't tell what you intend your question to be, but maybe after you edit your post it will become clear.  For the meaning of "one-to-one" please [choose your favorite reference](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=one-to-one+transformation).