# Calculating standard error of a coefficient that is calculated from other estimated coefficient

Tags: data-transformation, standard-error, regression-coefficients, nls

I'm working on the Gompertz growth model to fit weight at age: $$ m(a)=m_{\infty}e^{-\gamma exp(-g{1}a)}$$

Where $m_{\infty}$ and $g_{1}$ are coefficients to be estimated.

To deal with lack of normality I transformed my data using Box&Cox, and to deal with heterogeneity I used  weights. After applying *Box&Cox* I fit a model with the **R** function `nls()` and I used this model's residuals as weights $(w_{i}=1/StudentizedResiduals_{i})$ in a new fitting.

I need to estimate the coefficient $\mu=m_{\infty}e^{-1}$ and its standard error.

**Question 1:** As I've got $m_{\infty}$ and its standard error estimated with `nls()`, so Can I calculate the standard error of $\mu$ like this:$$StdErr(\mu)=StdErr(m_{\infty})e^{-1}$$

Or should I estimate this estandard error in a different way?

**Question 2:** As a result of the *Box&Cox* application my estimated coefficients are in a different scale and it's difficult to interpret them. From [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27067/back-transformation-of-regression-coefficients) I understand that I can't transform-back the coefficients, but any suggestion how make easier the interpretation of 'transformed' coefficients?

Thanks in advance