# Transformation of a regression coefficient when independent variable was log-transdormed

Tags: regression, data-transformation, regression-coefficients

In the context of a linear regression model where the independent variable ($X$) was log-transformed, like:

$Y = \alpha + \beta·ln(X)$

Is there a straightforward way to transform a regression coefficient ($\beta$) that was estimated using log-transformed independent variable $X$?

I know that in this model, an increase of 1% in $X$ would mean an increase of $\beta·ln(X)$ in the value of $Y$.

Is there a way to transform $\beta$ so I could say that an increase of 1% in $X$ means an increase of $\beta'·X $ in variable $Y$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back-transformation of regression coefficients](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27067/back-transformation-of-regression-coefficients)

Comment: Since $X$ was transformed, not $\beta$, a "back-transformation" of $\beta$ would seem to make no sense.  Could you clarify what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: $\beta$ is estimated here using $ln(X)$, so interpretation dependens on $ln(X)$ [as in the main text: an increase of 1% in $X$ results in an increase of $\beta·ln(X)$ for $Y$]. What I wonder to achieve (if possible) is an expression of the change in $Y$ due to $X$ in terms not of $ln(X)$ but $X$ itself, using $ln(X)$ in regression analysis.

Comment: But of course: it's right in front of us.  If $X$ changes to $\alpha X$ (for positive $\alpha$, of course) then $\log(X)$ becomes $\log(\alpha)+\log(X)$, whence $Y$ becomes $Y + \beta\log\alpha$.  *But there is no "back-transformation" of any sort needed in this analysis.*

Comment: @whuber, why not develop that into an answer? I don't see an answer beyond that, and this isn't really a duplicate of the linked thread as it is about the transformation of Y whereas this is about the transformation of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transform in the sense you'd wish in the question, i.e. preserving the interpretation of the coefficient $\beta$. In the log transformed regression $\beta$ becomes the sensitivity of the dependent variable to the *percentage change* in the independent variable (IV), instead of the sensitivity to the simple *change* in IV. In other words, $\beta$ in the log transformed case isthe measure of the *relative* sensitivity rather than *absolute* one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some intuition **for small changes** in $X$ by considering

$$
\begin{align}
Y+\delta Y&=\alpha + \beta \ln(X + \delta X)\\
&=\underbrace{\alpha + \beta \ln X}_Y + \beta\ln\left(1+\frac{\delta X}{X}\right)\\
\therefore\delta Y&\approx \beta\frac{\delta X}{X},
\end{align}
$$

where the approximation is obtained by a Taylor series expansion of the logarithm to first order in $\delta X$.

In other words, a 1% increase in $X$ gives you an increase of $0.01\beta$ in the dependent variable. But this only holds **for small changes** in $X$.

Comment: When $\log(X)$ is used in a model, the natural way to represent changes to $X$ is *multiplicative,* not additive.  The question is clear about that: it refers to a "1% change," which is multiplicative.